# Nuxt 3 server on Windows not handling simultaneous requests?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm getting an issue where my Nuxt server is not handling simultaneous requests from clients but it is only happening on Windows.

When two or more requests hit the server, only one of them gets served, and the others just return with a 503 Server Unavailable response instead of being added to the queue.

I have tested this on ARM and Intel Linux machines which to not have the same problem. Plus, Docker images built on a Linux-based Node base image also have no problem handling requests.

I can't reproduce this sort of issue on frameworks like NextJS. I have also tried various versions on Node 14 and 16 including LTS. I think this may be a low level Nuxt Framework issue?

**Environment**

- OS: Windows 10
- Node version: v16.16.0
- Nuxt Version: 3.0.0-rc.11

**Reproduction**:

https://github.com/JeffreyTan1/nuxt-bug-reproduction

I scaffolded the project like so https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation/ and the api from here https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/server/

I use JMeter to simulate multiple users hitting the server at once. You can get JMeter from here: https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/ I have the distribution found at apache-jmeter-5.4.3.zip.

As a quick tutorial of how to setup a JMeter stress test:

- Unzip the download
- Go into the bin folder
- Open the ApacheJMeter JAR file (opens the GUI)
- [Create thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjXG6.png) and set the following [properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1KFf.png).
- [Create a HTTP Request sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3AVh.png) and set the following [properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kZ66.png)
- [Create a View Results Tree listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkCKt.png) and stay in this window
- Click the green play button and the gear+broomstick button to clear the output

You should see 200 responses interspersed by 503 responses.

**Edit**:

This is now in the hands of the nuxt/framework maintainers https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/8184